# how to add rule to auto change strings to use double quotes with yapf formatter and add comma after the last item of the list?

Tags: python, yapf

In the doc don't have a list available properties, and i find one file with some properties in gist.github, but i don't find the key for this rules.

Example of my problem:
I have this code:

```
endpoints = [
    path('check_email/', check_email)
]
```

and i want that this code will be formated to:

```
endpoints = [
    path("check_email/", check_email),
]
```

I have `setup.cfg` file with some settings:

```
[yapf]
# custom
based_on_style = google
split_before_logical_operator = True
align_closing_bracket_with_visual_indent = True
allow_multiline_dictionary_keys = True
allow_multiline_lambdas = True
blank_line_before_nested_class_or_def = True
indent_dictionary_value = True
dedent_closing_brackets = True
no_spaces_around_selected_binary_operators = set()
split_before_expression_after_opening_paren = True
split_arguments_when_comma_terminated = True
split_complex_comprehension = True
```

Comment: double quotes aren't pythonic (just check the docs, or "snth" in a repl), but if you want both of these things https://github.com/psf/black does it

Comment: @acushner have so many words that contains ' (such as don't, i'm etc), use double quotes as patterns makes more sense. And with black i will use two formatters? o.0

Comment: ah, for sentences like that, double quotes are pythonic. try it in a repl, you'll see.